# How can I configure Apache -Kylin Cube Planner?

Tags: java, spring, apache

I want test Cube planner in apache-kylin(2.3.0), so I created cube with segment, and I hit query to cube many times more than thousands but the cube planner there is no change in cuboid level like color changing and not get COUNT in exactly row count and other items.

Note:
Could u tell me?
Cube Planner Working only old Cube (like 3 month before) or new Cube also.

```
Configuration(kylin.Properties)
kylin.cube.cubeplanner.enabled=true
Kylin Version=2.3.0(SINGLE  NODE)
Cube creation =10days before
```

Answer (score 0):

Cube planner is divided into two phase. Phase 1 can recommend cuboid list based on estimated cuboid size before building the Cube, while phase 2 recommends cuboid list for existing Cube according to query statistics. In Kylin-2.3.0，cube planner isn't enabled by default.